# c++ code folding with emacs/cedet

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet

I would like to use the semantic code folding from the cedet package (emacs). I installed the 1.1 version and added the following lines to .emacs:

```
(load-file "~/software/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")

(require 'semantic-tag-folding)
(defun c-folding-hook ()
  (global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c <left>") 'semantic-tag-folding-fold-block)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c <right>") 'semantic-tag-folding-show-block)
)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'c-folding-hook)
```

Okay, when I now load a c oder c++ file, nothing happens when using the key bindings or directly running the corresponding commands. What's going wrong? Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't need to have `(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)` inside `defun` - it's better to run this command once...

But I think, that main problem is that you hadn't enabled any Semantic feature (see [this section in my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html#sec4)) - at least you need to call `(semantic-load-enable-minimum-features)` after loading of CEDET.

P.S. you code is working for me (I use `semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers` in my setup)

Answer (score 0):

try adding following line in your emacs config file after `(load-file "~/software/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")` line;

```
(semantic-load-enable-code-helpers) ; Enable prototype help and smart completion
```